# How to find words that contain string with a limited size

Tags: regex

I need to find all the words in an inputted text that has `(?i:val)` in it and are no longer that 5 characters.
So far I got: `\b([a-zA-Z]*(?i:val)[a-zA-Z]*){1,4}\b`

If we take this sample text to look in: `In computer science, a value is an expression which cannot be evaluated any further (a normal form). Val is also a match`

I get 3 matches (`value`, `evaluated` and `Val`), however `evaluated` should not match the pattern, as it is too long. What is the right way to get this straight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern does not account for the length of the words matched.

Use word boundaries and a lookahead like this:

```
(?i)\b(?=\w*val)\w{1,5}\b
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pD0hJ1/1)

The regex matches:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary since the next pattern is `\w`
- `(?=\w*val)` -  a lookahead making sure there is a `val` substring after zero or more word characters
- `\w{1,5}` - matches 1 to 5 word characters
- `\b` - trailing word boundary that stops words of more than 5 characters long from matching

You may use an ASCII JS version of the regex:

```
/\b(?=[a-z]*val)[a-z]{1,5}\b/i
```

Comment: The original regex `\b([a-zA-Z]*(?i:val)[a-zA-Z]*){1,4}\b` finds a word boundary with `\b`, then matches *zero **or more*** (no idea how many) letters from a-zA-Z ranges, then matches `val` in a case insensitive way, then again zero or more a-zA-Z letters - that is why it does not account for the length of the words matched.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand why the "evaluated" was matched. Note:

- `[a-zA-Z]*` matches the "e"
- `(?i:val)` matches "val"
- `[a-zA-Z]*` matches "uated"

Actually there's not repetition here! The pattern was matched in only one iteration.

You can achieve what you want using [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but I think that regex is not the best tool for this task. I highly recommend you using other functions depending on what you have.

Comment: Regex is a good tool for this specific task unless there are thousands of `val` to account for.

Comment: @stribizhev If I have a high-level language available, I would prefer using build-in methods (length, contains..). It really reduces that complexity.

Comment: True about using an other tool when possible, unfortunately, I can only use regex in this case..